# Защита от ввода буквенных символов с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Проблема в том, что после ввода правильного значения (цифры), не предлагается вводить другое значение - size2. Как исправить?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "MyClass.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    MyClass a,b;  
    int size1, size2; 
    cout<<"Enter first size : "; 
    while (!(cin >> size1) || (cin.peek() != '\n')) {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "nepravilno";
    }
    cin>>size1;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter second size : ";
    cin>>size2;
    cout<<endl;
    a.set_mass(size1);  
    b.set_mass(size2);
    a.show_mass(); 
    cout<<endl;
    b.show_mass();  
    cout<<endl<<" intersection rezult : "<<endl;
    a.intersection(b); 
    getch();  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как-то я не вижу у вас проверки ввода, кроме как на символ '\n'...

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите:

```
while (!(cin >> size1) || (cin.peek() != '\n')) {
    cin.clear();
    while (cin.get() != '\n');
    cout << "nepravilno";
}
cin>>size1;
```

В первой строке (внутри `while`) вы **уже** считали `size1`. После этого вы влетаете в его считывание **второй раз** - в

```
cin>>size1;
```

и понятно, что до вывода приглашения ввести второе число дело не доходит...